# You gave us a visitor for the node type TSInstantiationExpression but it's not a valid type

Tags: javascript, expo, babeljs, react-native-gesture-handler

After expo update, my project not working

The error is:

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\src\index.ts: [BABEL] D:\data\Anonymous\ReactNative\test\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\src\index.ts: You gave us a visitor for the node type TSInstantiationExpression but it's not a valid type
```

The dependencies of the project are:

```
packages: {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-45.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
}
```

Comment: Any fix @anonymous pro ?

Answer (score 3):

I´ve encountered the same error, fixed it by upgrading my expo-cli with `yarn global add expo-cli`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it still shows the error.

Answer (score 1):

After couple of days struggling found what caused the issue. Everything started with the release of `babel-core: 7.18.0`. The problem in my case was different versions of `babel` in my project and `expo`. Fixed it by upgrading `expo`'s version in `%APPDATA%\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\package.json`. You should delete node_modules in this folder and run `npm install`. I would say your issue is similar but with different package

Comment: hi, where do i find this file?

Comment: Which one do you mean?

Comment: where do i find %APPDATA% ?

Comment: just type %APPDATA% in file explorer (Windows)

Comment: What about mac?

Answer (score 0):

Its either an issue with the new v7.18.0 babel core release or a conflict with expo if you are using an older version. In my project we're using "expo": "41" and as a result, I needed to locked babel core to version "@babel/core": "7.17.12".

Comment: how do i lock bable/core?

Answer (score 0):

`pnpm add -g expo-cli` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score -2):

Delete node_modules and package-lock.json on your project directory and run the following commands
npm install and
expo start -c

Answer (score -2):

rm -rf ./node_modules && rm yarn.lock && yarn (for yarn)

OR

rm -rf ./node_modules && npm i (for npm)

Comment: still not working