# Why am I getting this error if I am importing Navigator library in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am using react native under expo and have installed the required dependencies to install navigator. This is my code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import Landing from './components/Landing';
import Beach from './components/Beach';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Landing></Landing>
  );
}
```

If I compile this, I am getting this error:

```
Error: [BABEL] G:\IntrotoIT\beach-app\node_modules\@react-navigation\stack\src\index.tsx: You gave us a visitor for the node type TSInstantiationExpression but it's not a valid type
    at verify (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\visitors.js:108:13)
    at Function.explode (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\visitors.js:30:3)
    at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:269:42
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:24:3)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\gensync\index.js:251:28)
    at Function.sync (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\gensync\index.js:89:14)
    at sync (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:67:25)
```

I seriously don't have clue on how to fix it. Tried deleting node modules and then `npm install` but it was of no use.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72328356/you-gave-us-a-visitor-for-the-node-type-tsinstantiationexpression-but-its-not-a

Comment: Unfortunately I went over it and of no use.